How do I fix the abandoned package issue after catkin build
I have been trying to build my workspace after making a new package, however when I do catkin build only 15 out of 50 packages are build, most of them are abandoned and a few fail. I think it has something to with dependencies but I can I track that. Is there an easy solution to this?


Find the package(s) that fail and look at their failure messages
Resolve them. If you're missing dependencies, use rosdep install to install them: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Rosdep.html. If the build is failing for other reasons, debug.
Try again :-)

